# What is equivalent of `List` of C#

Tags: go

In `C#` I used to have a `List` which can be referenced to elements by index and had a method to add elements. In Go, I am having difficulty in having such data type. If I use slice I cannot know its `size`. In the list I cannot access elements directly. What would be perfect data type for my case: I want to have a list and when needed I need to add item and when needed I should be able select single item directly. Shall I implement indexing to `List` ? Or is there any equivalent data type?

Comment: "If I use slice I cannot know its size" Why not? `len(list)`?

Comment: what you've described perfectly fits the slice's API:
add new item: `s = append(a, newitem)`
access item: `s[2]`
find out the size: `len(s)`

Comment: Just a humle remainder that Go is not object oriented. For example `arr.length` doesnot gives the length instead `len(arr)` does.

Comment: Please take the [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/). It explains all the basics of Go, including the core data types and how to use them, like [how to get the length of a slice](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/11).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a slice. You can get the length, add items and retrieve items using an index:

```
array := []int{1,2,3}
fmt.Println("Length: ", len(array))
array = append(array, 4)
fmt.Println("Item at last index", array[3])
```